# IntelliJ IDEA with hibernate support

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ IDEA 8.1.3.

It has support for a hibernate facet/plugin which I have enabled.  When I do this it recognises the HQL query strings but highlights in red all the objects and properties.  I can't see how to get IDEA to be aware of my entities.

I use spring+hibernate and annotated objects.  I have no hibernate.cfg.xml just a spring bean using `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?  Does the standard IntelliJ support this?

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to configure the datasource for your application. Usually to get this done you can directly access the auto-correction menu (<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>) and it will ask you to associate a datasource to your hibernate facet.

Comment: I don't really have a fixed datasource as I test with different DBs.  All I want is for IDEA to parse my annotated hibernate objects and be able to check my HQL using that info.

Answer (score 0):

I do the same in that I use a number of datasources, however, IntelliJ just wants to be able to locate the table names and columns so that it can autocomplete and lookup correctly.

I presume that the table and column names are the same between data sources.  If they are, then all I do is use the SQL create scripts (which I exported from one of he databases) to create DDL datasource inside the Datasources menu.